# Change MYSQL value automatically on next date

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL database and I have to make a link active for just one day, So I want that the value of a column should changed after one day so that link disabled on next day.

Is any technique available in MySQL to change value on next date automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier approach would be to just perform a check against the date column for each link, and only return the record(s) corresponding to the current date, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE link_date = CURDATE();
```

Comment: But, I have different scenario, I have a main server page which runs when there is no exam. But when if any exam on the day, I get the URL on exam page from database. So I want when I upload the exam for current day a flag should be ON and when I get flag ON on main page, it automatic redirect to exam page. On next day main page should run normally while flag is OFF (should be done automatically in database).

Answer (score 0):

use event do schedule job..

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1 ;

DROP EVENT IF EXISTS update_event;
CREATE EVENT update_event
on schedule EVERY 1 day
do update table_t set column_c = ? where link_date = DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 day);
```

Comment: Is this for whole database?